# Regex: Select everything (the whole line) to the dot but not more dots

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this 2 cases:

```
1. I love you.

2. I love you...
```

I want to select with regex only the first line to the dot, but not the second that has more dots.

I made this regex, but is not to good: `^(.+?\.)\K{0,3}$` or `^(.+?\.)(?!{1,1})$` or `^.*?!\.{1,3}$`

Maybe someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIND: `[^.\r\n]+\.(?!\.)`

or

FIND:  `^.*(?<!\.)\.$`

Source: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20796/regex-select-everything-the-whole-line-to-the-dot-but-not-more-dots